# Continue reading stdin until "END" in Scala?

Tags: scala, io, iterator, stdin, scala-2.10

How do I continue reading `stdin` until "END" string reached, in Scala?

Here's what I've tried:

```
val text = Iterator.continually(Console.readLine).takeWhile(_ != "END").toString
```

Comment: What didn't work as expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `mkString` instead of `toString` here:

```
val text = Iterator.
    continually(Console.readLine).
    takeWhile(_ != "END").
    mkString("\n")
```

`mkString` on collection aggregates all elements in a string using optional separator.

Answer (score 2):

`Conole.readLine` is deprecated. Use `io.StdIn.readLine` instead. Here a complete program with your code fragment. The only change I made is that it reads the entire input, until the user presses Ctrl-D or EOF is encountered:

```
import io.StdIn.readLine

object Reader extends App {
  val x = Iterator
    .continually(readLine)
    .takeWhile(_ != null)
    .mkString("\n")
  println(s"STDIN was: $x")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple recursion function like this:

```
def r(s: String = ""): String = {
  val l = readLine
  if (l == "END") s
  else r(s + l)
}
```

You can call it `r("")` it return result string

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this:

```
var buffer = ""
Iterator.continually(Console.readLine).takeWhile(_ != "END").foreach(buffer += _)
val text = buffer
```